# How to add ajax action to jsp page?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have to add ajax action to date field. When user choose appropriate date, it should show at table all free apartment.

How to implement this at jsp page. I'm newly at JavaEE.

Here is content of page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page errorPage="error/errHandler.jsp" %>

<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf" />

<html>
<head>
    <title>Reservation an apartment</title>
    <h1 align="left">Reservation an apartment</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bookRoom">
        <div class="reservation-group" align="left">
            <label class="places-label">Couch places at room</label>
            <span class="selections">
                <select id="r_select">
                    <option>select</option>
                    <option>1 person</option>
                    <option>2 persons</option>
                    <option>3 persons</option>
                    <option>4 persons</option>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="reservation-group" align="left">
            <label>Star rating</label>
            <select>
                <option>select</option>
                <option>2 stars</option>
                <option>3 stars</option>
                <option>4 stars</option>
                <option>5 stars</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div align="left">
            <label>Check-in date</label>
            <input type="date" placeholder="yy/mm/dd"/>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div align="left">
            <label>Check-out date</label>
            <input type="date"/>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div class="register-group" align="left">
            <div class="selections">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn" />
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How does this ajax technologist works on jsp in general? Do we need to use javascript or jquery? If yes, how exactly will be right.

Looking of the page:

[image: room register]

I want to understand this implementation. Any suggestions are appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the type of server-side view rendering technology you are using (in your case JSP), it's a question of having some JavaScript code react on a change in the date select box and then trigger a call to a server function that returns the available apartments given the entered date.

JQuery *is* JavaScript, it's a commonly used JavaScript framework. And yes, you could very well use it for this task. Just add an id to your date select box (for example "checkindate"):

`<input id="checkindate" type="date" placeholder="yy/mm/dd"/>`

and then use JQuery to attach code to the change event which calls your server with the selected date:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#checkindate").change(function(event) {
        var selectedDate = event.target.value;

        $.get("/your/server/function?selectedDate=" + selectedDate, function(data) {
            // populate list with data
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

Your server function will have to read the query parameter "selectedDate" and with that construct a list of available apartments in (for example) [JSON](http://json.org/) format and return that to the client.

Comment: I misunderstand what to add to select box? all is the same.

Comment: Just add an id to your select box, so that you can reference it from JavaScript. Add the code I provided to your web page and make sure to load the JQuery JavaScript file:
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

You will have to add your own code in order to populate your list with the data you received from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use onchange event as ,

```
<input type="date" placeholder="yy/mm/dd" onchange="sendAjax()" id="checkInDate" />
```

You jquery will be ,

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {


    });

    function sendAjax() {
        var checkInDate= $("#checkInDate").val();
        //var checkOutDate= $("#checkOutDate").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "You URL path"
            data: "checkInDate" + checkInDate,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response) {

                //alert("Success : "+response);
                if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null"){
                    //do you stuff here
                }

            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e.message);
            },
        });
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onChange event and and send  the ajax call on onChange event.

You can use onClick,onblur() event too

```
<script>

function onDateChange(){

//Alert OnChange is Called
alert("Date Changed");

//Send ajax call


}

</script>
```